# "common_google_play_services_install_title" error

Tags: android, google-play-services

I am trying to export my application which uses google play services library. But there is a lint warning which prevents me to export the app even though I've cleaned the project. But its running fine in the emulator.Here is the warning it shows:

```
"common_google_play_services_install_title" is translated here but not found in default locale
Issue: Checks for translations that appear to be unused (no default language string)
Id: ExtraTranslation
If a string appears in a specific language translation file, but there is no corresponding string in the default locale, then this string is probably unused. (It's technically possible that your application is only intended to run in a specific locale, but it's still a good idea to provide a fallback.).
Note that these strings can lead to crashes if the string is looked up on any locale not providing a translation, so it's important to clean them up.[]
```

Can someone help me out with this?? I'm stuck up here very badly..

Comment: Try Window--> Preferences-->Android-->Lint Error Checking -->Uncheck both the options --> apply --> OK.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go to Window in Eclipse and then to Preferences.
Click on the arrow beside Android and you will find Lint Error Checking.
Uncheck the second checkbox which says "Run full error check when exporting the app and abort if fatal errors are found."
And you are good to go.